# How to load webView from custom position number in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, android-webview

In my application I want to use **horizontal swipe** `webview` and for this, I find below library.
https://github.com/GautamChibde/Android-Horizontal-Swipe-WebView

But I want start page to be my custom page number but it always starts from the first page.
For example, I want to start from **page 3**.

**This custom webView codes:**

```
class HorizontalWebView2(context: Context,
                         attrs: AttributeSet) : WebView(context, attrs) {
    private var x1 = -1f
    private var pageCount = 0
    private var currentPage = 0
    private var currentX = 0
    private var delta: Int = 30
    private var pageNumber: Int = 1

    private val prevPagePosition: Int
        get() = ceil((--currentPage * this.measuredWidth).toDouble()).toInt()

    private val nextPagePosition: Int
        get() = ceil((++currentPage * this.measuredWidth).toDouble()).toInt()

    init {
        setDelta()
        this.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                injectJavascript()
            }
        }

        this.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onJsAlert(view: WebView, url: String, message: String, result: JsResult): Boolean {
                val pageCount = Integer.parseInt(message)
                this@HorizontalWebView2.setPageCount(pageCount)
                injectCSS()
                result.confirm()
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setDelta() {
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        (context as Activity).windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        delta = (displayMetrics.widthPixels * 0.04).toInt()
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> super.onTouchEvent(event)
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                x1 = event.x
                return super.onTouchEvent(event)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                val x2 = event.x
                val deltaX = x2 - x1
                if (abs(deltaX) > delta) {
                    // Left to Right swipe action
                    return if (x2 > x1) {
                        turnPageLeft(deltaX)
                        true
                    } else {
                        turnPageRight(deltaX)
                        true
                    }// Right to left swipe action
                }
            }
            else -> super.onTouchEvent(event)
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event)
    }

    private fun turnPageLeft(deltaX: Float) {
        if (currentPage > 0) {
            val scrollX = prevPagePosition
            loadAnimation(scrollX, deltaX)
            currentX = scrollX
            scrollTo(scrollX, 0)
            pageNumber--
            EventBus.getDefault().post(EventPageNumber(pageNumber))
        }
    }

    private fun turnPageRight(deltaX: Float) {
        if (currentPage < pageCount - 1) {
            val scrollX = nextPagePosition
            loadAnimation(scrollX + PADDING_OFFSET, deltaX)
            currentX = scrollX + PADDING_OFFSET
            scrollTo(scrollX + PADDING_OFFSET, 0)
            pageNumber++
            EventBus.getDefault().post(EventPageNumber(pageNumber))
        }
    }

    private fun loadAnimation(scrollX: Int, deltaX: Float) {
        val anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "scrollX",
                currentX - deltaX.toInt(), scrollX)
        anim.duration = SCROLL_DURATION
        anim.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        anim.start()
    }

    private fun injectJavascript() {
        val js = "function initialize(){\n" +
                "    var d = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];\n" +
                "    var ourH = window.innerHeight - 40;\n" +
                "    var ourW = window.innerWidth - (2*20);\n" +
                "    var fullH = d.offsetHeight;\n" +
                "    var pageCount = Math.floor(fullH/ourH)+1;\n" +
                "    var currentPage = 0;\n" +
                "    var newW = pageCount*window.innerWidth - (2*20);\n" +
                "    d.style.height = ourH+'px';\n" +
                "    d.style.width = newW+'px';\n" +
                "    d.style.margin = 0;\n" +
                "    d.style.webkitColumnGap = '40px';\n" +
                "    d.style.webkitColumnCount = pageCount;\n" +
                "    document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + '<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"height=device-height, user-scalable=no\" />';" +
                "    return pageCount;\n" +
                "}"
        this.loadUrl("javascript:$js")
        this.loadUrl("javascript:alert(initialize())")
    }

    private fun injectCSS() {
        this.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
                "style.type = 'text/css';" +
                "style.innerHTML = 'body { padding: 20px 20px !important; }';" +
                "parent.appendChild(style)" +
                "})()")
    }

    fun setPageCount(pageCount: Int) {
        this.pageCount = pageCount
    }

    fun getPageCount(): Int {
        return pageCount
    }

    companion object {
        const val SCROLL_DURATION: Long = 400
        const val PADDING_OFFSET = 10
    }
}
```

How can I fix it and start from custom page number?

Comment: set currentPage  = 3 and then try it. and change condition on turnPageLeft method.

Comment: @ViralPatel That will be static option. Instead make a constructor and set current position in that, so by that you will be able to pass whichever position you want to.

Comment: @ViralPatel, i changed currentPage but not change any page! but how can i change turnLeft method? can you send to me code? please

Comment: @VirRajpurohit , thanks my friend . can you send to me code? please. i really need your help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing below pseudo code by which you can get idea of how the library code is working.

Create method in your `HorizontalWebView.kt` as below

```
fun setPageNumber(number: Int) {
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        (context as Activity).windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        currentX = (number * displayMetrics.widthPixels) + PADDING_OFFSET
        scrollTo(currentX + PADDING_OFFSET, 0)
    }
```

Now from your `MainActivity.kt` call above method.

```
val wv = findViewById<HorizontalWebView>(R.id.web_view)
        wv.setPageNumber(3)// Page you want to load
        wv.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ch03.html")
```

> NOTE: You can raise as an issue in github link for above project. The above code is just quick pseudo code which requires more validations and improvement.

Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, not pass static value on `currentPage`

**FirstActivity.kt**

```
val showButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)

// Setting On Click Listener
showButton.setOnClickListener {
    // Getting the user input
    if(editText.text.trim().toString().isEmpty()){
        editText.setText("0")
    }
    var textGet = editText.text
    val intent = Intent(this@FirstActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("number",textGet.toString().toInt())
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
var number = intent.getIntExtra("number",0)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
}
val wv = findViewById<HorizontalWebView>(R.id.web_view)
wv.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
wv.setPageNumber(number)
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ch03.html")
```

and then follow the @Vir Rajpurohit  **HorizontalWebView.kt**

```
fun setPageNumber(number: Int) {
    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    (context as Activity).windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
    currentX = (number * displayMetrics.widthPixels) + PADDING_OFFSET
    scrollTo(currentX + PADDING_OFFSET, 0)
}
```

[image]

If we click on direct **NEXT** `Button` then pass 0 value.

I hope it'll help you...!